How to Use OpenAI API for Embedding Generation with ChromaDB Without LangChain?
I have been using OpenAIEmbeddings from LangChain, which is a model that doesn't require text input directly. I use it to store vector embeddings in ChromaDB with the following code:
db = Chroma(persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH, embedding_function=get_embedding())

Now, I want to use the OpenAI API directly without relying on LangChain. I am calling the API as follows:
client = OpenAI()

response = client.embeddings.create(
    model=model,
    input=[text]
)

The issue is that this function requires text input, whereas the embedding_function parameter for ChromaDB does not take text input in its function.
I tried to iterate over the documents and embed each item individually like this:
for chunk in chunks_with_ids:
    chunk_embedding = get_openai_embedding(chunk.page_content)
    chunk.metadata["embeddings"] = chunk_embedding

However, since there is already an embedding_function parameter in ChromaDB, I expected there might be a more integrated way to use the OpenAI API directly for generating embeddings and storing them in ChromaDB.
How can I resolve this mismatch and directly use the OpenAI API to generate embeddings and store them in ChromaDB?

If you create your collection using an embedding function then chroma will automatically use it when you add docs to the collection.  Something like:
openai_ef = embedding_functions.OpenAIEmbeddingFunction(api_key=openai.api_key, model_name="text-embedding-3-small")
collection = client.create_collection(name=name, embedding_function=openai_ef)
